# twisted: check whether a deferred has already been called

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

This is what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm making a remote call to a server for information, and I want to block to wait for the info. I created a function that returns a Deferred such that when the RPC comes in with the reply, the deferred is called. Then I have a function called from a thread that goes `threads.blockingCallFromThread(reactor, deferredfunc, args)`.

If something goes wrong - for example, the server goes down - then the call will never un-block. I'd prefer the deferred to go off with an exception in these cases.

I partially succeeded. I have a deferred, `onConnectionLost` which goes off when the connection is lost. I modified my blocking call function to:

```
    deferred = deferredfunc(args)
    self.onConnectionLost.addCallback(lambda _: deferred.errback(
        failure.Failure(Exception("connection lost while getting run"))))
    result = threads.blockingCallFromThread(
        reactor, lambda _: deferred, None)
    return result
```

This works fine. If the server goes down, the connection is lost, and the errback is triggered. However, if the server does not go down and everything shuts down cleanly, `onConnectionLost` still gets fired, and the anonymous callback here attempts to trigger the errback, causing an `AlreadyCalled` exception to be raised.

Is there any neat way to check that a deferred has already been fired? I want to avoid wrapping it in a `try/except` block, but I can always resort to that if that's the only way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are ways, but you really shouldn't do it.  Your code that is firing the `Deferred` should be keeping track of whether it's fired the `Deferred` or not in the associated state.  Really, when you fire the `Deferred`, you should lose track of it so that it can get properly garbage collected; that way you never need to worry about calling it twice, since you won't have a reference to it any more.

Also, it looks like you're calling `deferredfunc` from the same thread that you're calling `blockingCallFromThread`.  Don't do that; functions which return `Deferreds` are most likely calling reactor APIs, and those APIs are **not thread safe**.  In fact, `Deferred` itself is not thread safe.  This is why it's `blocking`*`Call`*`FromThread`, not `blockOnThisDeferredFromThread`.  You should do `blockingCallFromThread(reactor, deferredfunc, args)`.

If you really want errback-if-it's-been-called-otherwise-do-nothing behavior, you may want to [cancel](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.cancel.html) the Deferred.

Comment: so how would i cancel the deferred if i don't have access to it, since  i must call `blockingCallFromThread` to be thread-safe? is the only way to modify that function to do `onConnectionLost.addCallback(lambda _: d.cancel())`, where `d` is the deferred it's about to return? this would mean having to pass it the onconnectionlost deferred

Comment: You can call `blockingCallFromThread(self.something)`, where `self.something` holds on to the `Deferred` for you.  The problem is calling into reactor APIs from the wrong thread, not from the wrong object.

Comment: yep I ended up doing that. i couldn't get .cancel to work, however - it seemed to have no effect. i just made a helper function which takes a deferred and tries to trigger an errback. are there any nuances to `.cancel` that i'm not aware of? from the docs it seemed if i do nothing special, `.cancel` should trigger a CancelledError errback if it hasn't been called, and do nothing otherwise.

Comment: You're asking a bunch of questions here and I'm only half-sure what yo mean by most of them.  If you post another top-level question that is much more specific (i.e. includes a <http://sscce.org/>), I'll try to answer it.